# Stacked barplot beside each other

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked

I am trying to construct a stacked barplot against beside each other but only thing I was able to produce was two seaprate stacked barplot. Here is a sample data

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

i<-c(49.36,42.61,40.14,41.33)
ls<-c(49.27,47.4,57.39,56.02)
us<-c(1.37,9.99,2.48,2.65)
dat<-as.matrix(rbind(i,ls,us))
colnames(dat)<-colnames(dat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = c("bc","hd","he","mi"))
barplot(dat,col=c("green4","Orange","orangered4"),names.arg = c("BC","HD","HE","MI"))

i<-c(55.76,56.96,52.09,41.76)
ls<-c(39.03,40.05,45.77,50.04)
us<-c(5.21,2.99,2.13,8.20)
dat1<-as.matrix(rbind(i,ls,us))
colnames(dat1)<-colnames(dat1, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = c("bc","hd","he","mi"))
barplot(dat1,col=c("green4","Orange","orangered4"),names.arg = c("BC","HD","HE","MI"))
```

And this is the resultant figure:

[image]
What I am trying to do is combine these two plots into single plot such that BC and BC1 are next to each other, HD and HD1 are next to each other and so on. I think the function `beside = T` is useful here but this is all I know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe (where I've changed the column names in the second data frame so all column names will be unique):

```
# Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/101023.html
interleave <- function(v1,v2)
{
  ord1 <- 2*(1:length(v1))-1
  ord2 <- 2*(1:length(v2))
  c(v1,v2)[order(c(ord1,ord2))]
}

i<-c(49.36,42.61,40.14,41.33)
ls<-c(49.27,47.4,57.39,56.02)
us<-c(1.37,9.99,2.48,2.65)
dat<-as.matrix(rbind(i,ls,us))
colnames(dat) <- colnames(dat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = c("bc","hd","he","mi"))

i<-c(55.76,56.96,52.09,41.76)
ls<-c(39.03,40.05,45.77,50.04)
us<-c(5.21,2.99,2.13,8.20)
dat1<-as.matrix(rbind(i,ls,us))
colnames(dat1) <- colnames(dat1, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = c("bc1","hd1","he1","mi1"))

dat2 = cbind(dat, dat1)[ , interleave(colnames(dat), colnames(dat1))]

barplot(dat2, col=c("green4","Orange","orangered4"))
```

[image]

You can even group the bars as follows:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,4))
lapply(seq(1,ncol(dat2),2), function(x) {
  if(x==1) {
    par(mar=c(5,3,2,0))
    barplot(dat2[,c(x,x+1)], col=c("green4","Orange","orangered4"))
  } else {
    par(mar=c(5,2,2,0))
    barplot(dat2[,c(x,x+1)], col=c("green4","Orange","orangered4"), yaxt="n")
  }
})
```

[image]